# RPi-2 : Red led flashes after few seconds

Tags: power-light

I recently saw that my Raspberry Pi's red light (power light) flashes every few seconds. Is this normal? If not what could be the cause?

I am using a raspberry pi 2 connected to a monitor, keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you may have a power issue :

> **Red power LED is blinking**
>
> A blinking red power LED indicates problems
> with the power supply. On model A and B, it is hard-wired to the 3.3V
> power supply rail. If it is blinking, as one user has reported[1] it
> means the 5V power supply is dropping out. Use a different power
> supply.
>
> On model B+ (and presumably also the A+), the circuit has been
> improved to give a much more reliable warning of poor power quality.
> The red power LED is wired to an APX803 supervisor[2] which kicks in
> when the 5V power supply drops below 4.63V[3]. If it does, the LED
> will blink. Check your connections, cable, and power supply.

https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Red_power_LED_is_blinking

What is the specification of your power supply?

Comment: Raspberry pi 2, i connected a micro usb o my iphone apple usb adapter, whcih outputs 5V, 1A. That should be enough shoudnt it? While the red light is flashing the raspberry pi dosent go offline, it stay up and running still.

Comment: I always used power supplies from Pi suppliers min 1.5A for my Pi2's and always use the official 5.1V 2.5A 18awg cable psu on my Pi3's.

Comment: Is it safe to run my raspberry pi 2 at 2.4A?

Comment: Also, i am constantly overclocking my pi 2 to 1000Mhz. Tried, 2.4A 5.2V supply, but on boot up red light flashes.

Comment: Yes, higher amps is fine. I would suggest buying the official psu - its best feature is the large diameter 18awg cable.

Answer (score 0):

Used a higher Amp USB socket, and works fine now.